# Why child's width does not expand into parent's width in display: table-cell?

Tags: css, css-tables

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>hello</p>
 </div>
```

Now the child element p here does not expand into its' parent's width and `height: 100px`, why?
If the `display: table-cell` changed into `display: table` or others such as `block`,
the child element `<p>` here does expand into its' parent's `width` and `height :100px`.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>hello</p>
 </div>
```

Is there a rule to explain the action here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` with `display: table-cell` is rendered in an anonymous table-row box, in an anonymous table box ([§17.2.1 Anonymous table objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#anonymous-boxes)), *within* the `div` (which then becomes this anonymous table box's containing block).

A table box doesn't expand to the width of its containing block by default ([§17.5.2 Table width algorithms: the 'table-layout' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#width-layout)). This is true of anonymous table boxes, HTML `table` elements, and any other element with `display: table`.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you asked,

**If you declare display:table-cell then you have to nest it within elements with display:table-row and display:table. Just like a real table.**

[The link which says about that usage](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table)

Explanation of table cell:

---

**`table-cell:`** Let the element behave like a `<td>` element

Using height with table-cell columns:

**Table-cell Columns expand to match the height of the largest column in the row. The height is defined by the content and not an explicit fixed height.**

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  height: 500px;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Column 1.</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2 is a bit longer.</div>
    <div class="column">Column 3 is longer with lots of text in it.</div>
</div>
```

**Column 1. Column 2 is a bit longer.   Column 3 is longer with lots of text in it.**

A common workaround for floated elements is to set a min-height value.

This works if the length of the longest content is always roughly the same, but isn’t a viable solution if the length of the content varies significantly.

[Here is a reference to this answer](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/)

---

Applying the rule to your answer:

---

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

---

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyLe5wfj/)

Comment: "If you declare display:table-cell then you have to nest it within elements with display:table-row and display:table. Just like a real table." This rule does not appear in your reference link, and I suspect it's made up.

Comment: @BoltClock, the link I have given is for the exanple I gave in the answer. Please read the answer again. And regarding the rule, check this link 
[CHeck this link](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table)

Comment: why directly the downvote, there is more information in the links I have given, and also check my second snippet and the fiddle.

Comment: Your made-up rule doesn't appear in that link either. I don't know what your examples are supposed to illustrate. Neither your example nor the links address the question in *any* way.

Comment: have you seen that link, it is mentioned there. It is visible as soon as you open the page.